# praat to get a list of frequencies duration from a WAV file

Tags: audio, signal-processing

Is there a way to use the software praat to get a list of  from a WAV file ?

Comment: What characteristics of the WAV file you want on a list?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [this](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/) praat phonetics analysis package appears to say that it has the capability to read a wav file and print a pitch contour analysis.  Is that what you need?